# Streaming job fails in HDP 2.0

Tags: hadoop, streaming, hortonworks-data-platform

Iam trying to run streaming job as below in HDP-2.0.6 cluster.

hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-101.jar -input /USER/city.txt -output /USER/streamout -mapper /bin/cat -reducer /bin/cat -numReduceTasks 2

(Referred: 
http://hortonworks.com/blog/using-r-and-other-non-java-languages-in-mapreduce-and-hive/

On executing the command iam getting an error as below.

**Streaming Command Failed!**

I couldn't find any other details from the console which would help me to track the issue.

But the same query is running in the local installation of hadoop-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-76 without any errors(same version of hadoop as in cluster, except that : in cluster- it is HDP installed using Ambari and in local-individual component hadoop installed manually from tarball).

Has any one came across such an issue ???
Or has any idea about the root cause?

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance..